# RabbitMQ / amqplib: Get wildcard binding key for message

Tags: rabbitmq, node-amqp

When consuming a message from a queue, I would like to retrieve the binding key (with wildcards) that was used to bind that queue to the exchange.

Is this possible somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Every received message has this field: `message.fields.routingKey`

Comment: Isn't this the specific routing key that matched the wildcard binding key?

Comment: Yes, it is. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope, I'm after the wildcard